# Sum of string array

Tags: java, android

I have an array of strings download from **`JSOUP`** which look along the line of:

```
[$1,234,24 $233,424,323 $15,324,132 .......]
```

How can I sum all of these values into one int?

**(They are String not int)**

Comment: is this `24 $233` you considering one or two different value..?

Comment: Is the number "$1,234,24" equal to the int value of "123424" or are 1, 234, and 24 all different numbers?

Comment: I think its american notation (or whatever it is called) so `1,234,24` is `123424`

Comment: what do you mean by **I think**, be sure before asking,else some one will flag or downvote question

Comment: I mean I am not 100% sure how this notation is called. I am sure though that the commas just seperate blocks within a number. I saw people struggling with this before.

Comment: @MartinS - commas separate thousands though, so `$1,234,24` is not a valid format in "american notation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: First remove all `$` and `,` and split with space, and then in for loop parse the `strings` to `integers` ans sum.

```
String[] array = "$1,234,24 $233,424,323 $15,324,132".replaceAll("[$,]", "").split(" ");
int sum = 0;
for (String element : array) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(element);
}
System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
```

And it is the result:

```
sum = 248871879
```

Comment: How is the sum of these three numbers which are all over one million equal to 1462? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Where is one million?? it is just a simple to show how to do this.

Comment: These are two of the numbers used: $233,424,323 $15,324,132. There is no way they could equal 1462 when added.

Comment: do not split by `,` but by space. Remove the commas

Comment: How do you know that is split by space, not by comma

Comment: Because the comma does not separate numbers here but blocks within a number. Also it's the only way the $ signs make sense ;)

Comment: OK now I did it as you said, I think maybe you are right. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that his question is not clear, So my focus was how to change String to Integer and sum the values.